# Zend_OpenId and Google login

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

i have done a very simple setup with a test [myopenid](https://www.myopenid.com/) account

```
require_once "Zend/OpenID/Consumer.php";

$openid_id = "http://testphp.myopenid.com/";
$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer();

if (!$consumer->login($openid_id, "http://localhost/php/openid/oid_return.php")) {
  die("failed");
}

echo "OK";
```

when i try to use Google OpenID (set `$openid_id = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"`) it fails. i guess that is just the endpoint/provider not the identifier. how can i then fix this problem? i guess it will be a similar fix for yahoo etc too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more info by calling $consumer->getError();

But I think Google OpenID is not supported (see http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-6905)

Answer (score 0):

Zend_OpenID not supported OpenID 2.0 protocol